# Custom "Swipeable" UIScrollView does not work properly on iPad - works fine on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiscrollview

I am working to make my iPhone app compatible for the iPad. The user can tap or swipe the screen to activate certain functions, and it works fine on my iPhone version. There is a UIScrollView on the page which I have subclassed to make it "swipeable," i.e. it passes up all of its touch functions to its superview as such:

```
 @implementation SwipeableScrollView

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];

    [self.superview touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];

}
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [super touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];

    [self.superview touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];
}

-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [super touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];

    [self.superview touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
} 

@end
```

This works fine on the iPhone version, passing both taps and swipe gestures, but on the iPad, I get the following strange behavior:

1. Taps are passed to the superview properly.
2. But, swipe gestures are not passed at all.

**Any idea why this would be working on the iPhone but not the iPad?**

Comment: Which version iPhone OS?

Comment: I am compiling against ios 4, and running the iPad on ios 3.2.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure why this is happening (I guess `UIScrollView` sort of needs to handle all the touches), but "split"'s solution in [this thread](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development-advanced-discussion/33496-uiscrollview-touch-events-delivering.html) helped me solve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, that UIScrollView on the iPad cancels content touches very fast, even if `canCancelContentTouches` is set to NO. Also, overwriting `-touchesShouldCancelInContentView:` does not help. Read more here: [link text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3910629/why-does-uiscrollview-cancel-my-touches-on-the-ipad-but-not-on-the-iphone)

Answer (score 0):

While overriding touch events was necessary on the iPhone, for the iPad Apple has introduced [UIGestureRecognizers](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/General/Conceptual/iPadProgrammingGuide/GestureSupport/GestureSupport.html) that make tasks like this much more straightforward and easy to implement. You will probably need to refactor your code to use them.

Comment: That still doesn't work in the iPad... now it just doesn't recognize any taps at all. But either way, if it worked on the iPhone, why should it stop working on the iPad?

Comment: Because Apple completely reworked the way touch events are delivered to controls. So you are saying that you have replaced your touch override code with a `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` and it still doesn't work?

Comment: Yes--that is exactly what happened.

Answer (score 0):

you can make custom uiscrollView and implements it's delegate so you can do what you want with scrollview it works with me fine

```
 #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
         @protocol ScrollingDelegate <NSObject>
         @required
        - (void)scrolltouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
        - (void)scrolltouchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
        - (void)scrolltouchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
         @end
```

Implementation

```
 @interface CustomScrollView : UIScrollView
 {
  id <ScrollingDelegate> delegate;

  }
  @property (nonatomic,strong) id scrollDelegate;
  @end

   #import "CustomScrollView.h"

   @implementation CustomScrollView
   @synthesize scrollDelegate;
   - (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
   {
  self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
  if (self) {
    // Initialization code
   }
   return self;
   }

  - (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
  {
  self=[super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
  if (self)
  {
  }
  return self;
  }
  -(BOOL)touchesShouldCancelInContentView:(UIView *)view
  {
   return NO;
  }

   - (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
   {
    [self.scrollDelegate scrolltouchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
    }

    - (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
   {
   [self.scrollDelegate scrolltouchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];
    }

   - (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
    {
    [self.scrollDelegate scrolltouchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];

    }

    -(void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
    {
    }
    @end
```